# How to create a lightbox window in jQuery that will end at the bottom of the content or show scrollbars if the contents do not fit?

Tags: jquery, css, overlay, lightbox

I need to create a lightbox window using jQuery *without* any plug-ins. The overlay needs to appear with content that is located within the page.

Can someone give me some pointers on how to make it so scrollbars will appear in a defined portion of the content if the browser's window is not high enough to fit the content? It will also need to adjust it's size in case upon page load the window is high enough, then if the user shrinks the window, then vertical scrollbars will appear around the defined portion of the content.

The lightbox should always appear 100px from the top of the page. If the contents are not that high, then the bottom of the lightbox should end where the content ends. If the contents are very high and cannot all be displayed by the bottom of the window, then scrollbars should appear in a designated section of the lightbox content.

This has to work in IE7+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is designed for the 100px margin-top you specified, as well as a 100px margin between the bottom of the element at its tallest and the bottom of the window. When the window is resized, the function iterates twice in case the window height is greater than that of the previously-squished lightbox (at which point, its height would be set to 'auto'), but ends up being shorter than the relaxed height of the newly expanded lightbox (in which case, we need to squish the lightbox again to match the new window height).

```
<div id="myLightBox">
    <div id="myScrollPane">

        <!-- Content here -->

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function resizeLightBox(i)
{
    if (window.innerHeight < $('#myLightbox').height() + 200)
    {
        var newHeight = (window.innerHeight - 200) + 'px';
        $('#myLightBox').css('height', newHeight);
        $('#myScrollPane').css('height', newHeight);
        $('#myScrollPane').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#myLightBox').css('height', 'auto');
        $('#myScrollPane').css('height', 'auto');
        $('#myScrollPane').css('overflow-y', 'visible');
    }
    if (i > 0)
    {
        i--;
        resizeLightBox(i);
    }
}

window.onload = function(){resizeLightBox(1)};
window.onresize = function(){resizeLightBox(2)};
</script>
```